# Validate JSON Schema in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

Please suggest the possible techniques to validate(NULL, NOT NULL, TAG presence, length, etc.) incoming request JSON schema elements in API Manager before backend service is invoked.

Is it recommended to perform schema level validation in WSO2 API Manager?
As per my knowledge, schema validations(XML/JSON) should be done at client side before API deployed on API Manager in invoked.

Any comments would be appreciated.

Regards,
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

In order to validate the request json you can use OpenAPI validation specifications. apim facilitates you to edit the OpernAPI spec from the UI it self.

As per my knowledge you can do the validation in both places, but if you do the validation in the client it self you can prevent the API invocation to api manager.

Comment: Thanks. Please help me to direct to the OpenAPI validation specification  document/link reference.